# SQL server automatically update table column

Tags: sql-server, trigger

The default column is now only restricted to having only 1 Y based on the membershipType column. Now, i am trying to set my defaults column able to automatically change to N if there is existing Y.

```
  ID  titlePromo   membershipType         defaults
    --  ----------   --------------         ------
    1    Promo 1     Membership Promotion      Y
    2    Promo 2     Membership Renewal        Y
    3    Promo 3     Membership Grad           Y
    4    Promo 4     Membership Promotion      N
    5    Promo 5     Membership Promotion      N
    6    Promo 6     Membership Grad           N
```

I found out i am able to use trigger method.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgDefaults ON dbo.Promotions AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS BEGIN; UPDATE dbo.Promotions SET defaults = 'N' WHERE defaults = 'Y' AND membershipType IN (SELECT membershipType FROM Inserted); END
```

Table name: dbo.Promotions
However, i am having error saying : Cannot create trigger on 'dbo.Promotions' as the target is not in the current database. 
Can someone tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server Mgmt Studio, 
first click on the database name that will contain your trigger, then click on New Query and type in your T-SQL w/o any schema info.
OR 
Use the following line of code before your CREATE TRIGGER batch of commands to be executed:

```
USE <databasename>
```

And in case cross-database is needed, you need to be using the current database first and then type fully qualified name of the table. Refer the following example:

```
Use <databasename>

GO

create trigger addtotable1

on databasename.dbo.tablename

for insert

as

insert into anotherdatabase.dbo.tablename

select databasename.dbo.tablename.userid, databasename.dbo.tablename.username, biadatabasename.dbo.tablename.issuperuser

from databasename.dbo.tablename, inserted

where databasename.dbo.tablename.userid = inserted.userid

and inserted.roleid = 3
```